# How can I get only one data from here?

Tags: python

There are 25 'high' values ​​here. I only need the last 5 'high' values. How can I print this?

```
import time
from cointiger_sdk import cointiger
from cointiger_sdk import const

try:
   klines = cointiger.kline('BTCusdt', '1day')
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp.status_code, flush=True)
    print(exp.message, flush=True)


print(klines)
```

Results:

```
{'symbol': 'BTCusdt', 'kline_data': [{'amount': 7603754.47963499, 'vol': 261.22667747, 'high': 29598.55, 'low': 28346.94, 'id': 1609430400, 'close': 29201.45, 'open': 28788.39}, {'amount': 9366200.634728, 'vol': 315.07069718, 'high': 32000.0, 'low': 28810.0, 'id': 1609516800, 'close': 31690.0, 'open': 29201.45}, {'amount': 11135575.75914899, 'vol': 336.79222767, 'high': 34700.0, 'low': 31054.47, 'id': 1609603200, 'close': 33577.29, 'open': 31646.7}, {'amount': 15524040.7626679, 'vol': 485.02459521, 'high': 33744.24, 'low': 27777.0, 'id': 1609689600, 'close': 31623.54, 'open': 33577.29}, {'amount': 22311810.105128, 'vol': 708.04087321, 'high': 32811.7, 'low': 30000.0, 'id': 1609776000, 'close': 32075.01, 'open': 31876.55}, {'amount': 15616150.03218152, 'vol': 457.57257943, 'high': 35800.0, 'low': 31822.91, 'id': 1609862400, 'close': 34543.51, 'open': 32071.34}, {'amount': 36088951.88101883, 'vol': 978.76081677, 'high': 38885.93, 'low': 34300.27, 'id': 1609948800, 'close': 38883.45, 'open': 34528.65}, {'amount': 21583805.28807, 'vol': 551.92535025, 'high': 41864.78, 'low': 36621.23, 'id': 1610035200, 'close': 40822.59, 'open': 38942.64}, {'amount': 18719707.64230584, 'vol': 465.24572668, 'high': 41514.7, 'low': 38779.03, 'id': 1610121600, 'close': 40558.94, 'open': 41367.62}, {'amount': 18541918.055294, 'vol': 459.86232336, 'high': 41500.0, 'low': 38747.5, 'id': 1610208000, 'close': 39706.29, 'open': 40541.26}, {'amount': 22222030.49987206, 'vol': 613.07816616, 'high': 39733.84, 'low': 31460.32, 'id': 1610294400, 'close': 31744.76, 'open': 39691.73}, {'amount': 20437506.08352799, 'vol': 598.29961432, 'high': 36538.49, 'low': 30300.0, 'id': 1610380800, 'close': 33884.46, 'open': 31600.13}, {'amount': 24826822.50564699, 'vol': 728.08125368, 'high': 35514.06, 'low': 32458.3, 'id': 1610467200, 'close': 34670.52, 'open': 33835.24}, {'amount': 24234425.969928, 'vol': 646.82568597, 'high': 40000.0, 'low': 34193.86, 'id': 1610553600, 'close': 39504.84, 'open': 34649.45}, {'amount': 43306024.37509642, 'vol': 1133.2043488, 'high': 40000.63, 'low': 35400.0, 'id': 1610640000, 'close': 35600.0, 'open': 39550.18}, {'amount': 98646762.0196114, 'vol': 2700.69012075, 'high': 37927.61, 'low': 34436.81, 'id': 1610726400, 'close': 37443.77, 'open': 35513.02}, {'amount': 57686421.22517199, 'vol': 1634.84306623, 'high': 37726.48, 'low': 33879.25, 'id': 1610812800, 'close': 35855.46, 'open': 37459.8}, {'amount': 79525692.120828, 'vol': 2208.87090469, 'high': 37447.65, 'low': 34800.0, 'id': 1610899200, 'close': 36409.76, 'open': 35752.94}, {'amount': 67764472.976666, 'vol': 1852.05605766, 'high': 37516.33, 'low': 35411.35, 'id': 1610985600, 'close': 37289.85, 'open': 36421.82}, {'amount': 89857399.9536664, 'vol': 2523.56027229, 'high': 37854.61, 'low': 34000.0, 'id': 1611072000, 'close': 34278.29, 'open': 37322.52}, {'amount': 95104892.564813, 'vol': 2831.5959, 'high': 35647.64, 'low': 31061.98, 'id': 1611158400, 'close': 31484.63, 'open': 34110.17}, {'amount': 114628713.66564983, 'vol': 3665.78544743, 'high': 32715.88, 'low': 29000.0, 'id': 1611244800, 'close': 32451.68, 'open': 31380.91}, {'amount': 81168623.46244699, 'vol': 2493.03904016, 'high': 33789.71, 'low': 31409.56, 'id': 1611331200, 'close': 31865.63, 'open': 32451.68}, {'amount': 56802788.201181, 'vol': 1757.4636126, 'high': 33047.17, 'low': 31670.22, 'id': 1611417600, 'close': 31932.26, 'open': 31811.3}, {'amount': 69454417.127135, 'vol': 2113.93198244, 'high': 34816.56, 'low': 30941.91, 'id': 1611504000, 'close': 34456.13, 'open': 31938.7}, {'amount': 91692648.861906, 'vol': 2841.59737503, 'high': 34624.9, 'low': 30867.9, 'id': 1611590400, 'close': 31749.29, 'open': 34447.48}, {'amount': 79150019.817521, 'vol': 2517.74738533, 'high': 32889.86, 'low': 29296.72, 'id': 1611676800, 'close': 30367.59, 'open': 31744.48}, {'amount': 86980578.654302, 'vol': 2806.93646872, 'high': 32180.34, 'low': 29510.08, 'id': 1611763200, 'close': 31903.12, 'open': 30337.76}, {'amount': 89219910.464338, 'vol': 2587.14274459, 'high': 38406.99, 'low': 31658.21, 'id': 1611849600, 'close': 37018.89, 'open': 31921.27}, {'amount': 93094773.769313, 'vol': 2713.34045574, 'high': 37486.14, 'low': 32860.55, 'id': 1611936000, 'close': 34230.26, 'open': 37188.03}, {'amount': 56367496.180922, 'vol': 1664.09039601, 'high': 34762.35, 'low': 32576.98, 'id': 1612022400, 'close': 32890.13, 'open': 34222.33}, {'amount': 69154181.62988499, 'vol': 2068.44589161, 'high': 34661.29, 'low': 32181.76, 'id': 1612108800, 'close': 33214.07, 'open': 32864.22}, {'amount': 53347657.96265899, 'vol': 1557.81190061, 'high': 35580.68, 'low': 33156.49, 'id': 1612195200, 'close': 34686.92, 'open': 33172.72}, {'amount': 46534524.12522699, 'vol': 1296.13740096, 'high': 36898.91, 'low': 34589.92, 'id': 1612281600, 'close': 36845.38, 'open': 34719.8}, {'amount': 50022712.5853, 'vol': 1337.36990876, 'high': 38671.71, 'low': 36220.63, 'id': 1612368000, 'close': 36601.55, 'open': 36855.31}, {'amount': 39699358.81216199, 'vol': 1063.54551956, 'high': 38239.99, 'low': 36421.8, 'id': 1612454400, 'close': 37962.94, 'open': 36570.97}, {'amount': 43308647.695469, 'vol': 1106.2258008, 'high': 40833.41, 'low': 37293.4, 'id': 1612540800, 'close': 40833.41, 'open': 37960.65}, {'amount': 49738418.871718, 'vol': 1274.04364753, 'high': 40920.41, 'low': 37700.0, 'id': 1612627200, 'close': 37902.18, 'open': 40852.05}, {'amount': 45903951.60456599, 'vol': 1160.56365005, 'high': 44082.01, 'low': 37366.4, 'id': 1612713600, 'close': 43558.88, 'open': 37894.66}, {'amount': 71802507.82686222, 'vol': 1569.39359045, 'high': 48095.65, 'low': 42573.87, 'id': 1612800000, 'close': 46874.44, 'open': 43600.13}, {'amount': 53765101.45515399, 'vol': 1160.037308, 'high': 47443.7, 'low': 43842.87, 'id': 1612886400, 'close': 44233.25, 'open': 46885.09}, {'amount': 51906896.83808296, 'vol': 1141.89121633, 'high': 48203.0, 'low': 43886.47, 'id': 1612972800, 'close': 47949.83, 'open': 44353.59}, {'amount': 47656074.30850899, 'vol': 1001.99101782, 'high': 48937.35, 'low': 45000.0, 'id': 1613059200, 'close': 47015.55, 'open': 47967.12}, {'amount': 38465142.102461, 'vol': 813.15742793, 'high': 48082.99, 'low': 46270.61, 'id': 1613145600, 'close': 47105.98, 'open': 47064.01}, {'amount': 31033788.907772, 'vol': 646.00858762, 'high': 49558.79, 'low': 46690.36, 'id': 1613232000, 'close': 48399.11, 'open': 47111.68}, {'amount': 31956415.65984399, 'vol': 666.38598854, 'high': 49260.73, 'low': 45000.0, 'id': 1613318400, 'close': 47964.39, 'open': 48606.85}, {'amount': 30222136.95975299, 'vol': 620.01469795, 'high': 50368.88, 'low': 46500.0, 'id': 1613404800, 'close': 49081.0, 'open': 48048.31}, {'amount': 30842011.31593499, 'vol': 618.35633582, 'high': 51632.02, 'low': 47100.0, 'id': 1613491200, 'close': 51123.27, 'open': 49061.6}, {'amount': 32310172.13913899, 'vol': 623.57162168, 'high': 52573.35, 'low': 50197.36, 'id': 1613577600, 'close': 51613.35, 'open': 51155.34}, {'amount': 32121226.485261, 'vol': 618.13196599, 'high': 53756.68, 'low': 50794.7, 'id': 1613664000, 'close': 53756.68, 'open': 51579.13}, {'amount': 42545913.96129599, 'vol': 762.07460227, 'high': 57544.77, 'low': 53500.0, 'id': 1613750400, 'close': 56086.16, 'open': 53800.0}, {'amount': 42970804.465124, 'vol': 759.13882826, 'high': 57779.75, 'low': 54000.0, 'id': 1613836800, 'close': 57292.24, 'open': 56094.99}, {'amount': 52744848.70982999, 'vol': 947.90609207, 'high': 58318.8, 'low': 48000.0, 'id': 1613923200, 'close': 53327.89, 'open': 57292.24}, {'amount': 54223611.38531299, 'vol': 1074.63808956, 'high': 54916.82, 'low': 45000.0, 'id': 1614009600, 'close': 48398.4, 'open': 53274.81}, {'amount': 39311243.37323985, 'vol': 799.28423822, 'high': 51307.56, 'low': 45000.0, 'id': 1614096000, 'close': 49553.27, 'open': 48658.07}, {'amount': 32839632.87762099, 'vol': 657.97740612, 'high': 51980.0, 'low': 48055.64, 'id': 1614182400, 'close': 50688.0, 'open': 49725.13}, {'amount': 30690980.44793999, 'vol': 648.94929232, 'high': 51305.19, 'low': 43000.0, 'id': 1614268800, 'close': 47694.11, 'open': 50500.0}, {'amount': 29280218.865672, 'vol': 620.86530132, 'high': 48399.95, 'low': 43007.08, 'id': 1614355200, 'close': 46638.8, 'open': 47658.39}, {'amount': 30625131.517423, 'vol': 672.53111188, 'high': 47501.97, 'low': 43000.0, 'id': 1614441600, 'close': 43400.91, 'open': 46482.11}, {'amount': 28293167.814562, 'vol': 614.19374898, 'high': 49214.57, 'low': 43074.57, 'id': 1614528000, 'close': 49126.74, 'open': 43356.96}, {'amount': 31678791.45315, 'vol': 647.8674, 'high': 50151.38, 'low': 47898.86, 'id': 1614614400, 'close': 48628.4, 'open': 49187.13}, {'amount': 31041905.727528, 'vol': 625.95050822, 'high': 52593.2, 'low': 47208.83, 'id': 1614700800, 'close': 50767.45, 'open': 48661.94}, {'amount': 29358432.478807, 'vol': 585.574095, 'high': 51704.72, 'low': 47867.72, 'id': 1614787200, 'close': 49446.64, 'open': 50785.54}, {'amount': 27319211.185092, 'vol': 573.33406914, 'high': 50003.23, 'low': 45600.0, 'id': 1614873600, 'close': 48144.44, 'open': 49413.84}, {'amount': 24829458.30798699, 'vol': 513.05851861, 'high': 49427.08, 'low': 46951.58, 'id': 1614960000, 'close': 47288.83, 'open': 47818.95}, {'amount': 23932871.13591655, 'vol': 483.35206304, 'high': 51226.62, 'low': 47143.04, 'id': 1615046400, 'close': 50555.56, 'open': 47271.02}, {'amount': 24217862.750016, 'vol': 479.03320894, 'high': 51820.42, 'low': 49383.75, 'id': 1615132800, 'close': 51049.57, 'open': 50555.56}, {'amount': 18516439.17104499, 'vol': 349.66597298, 'high': 54732.36, 'low': 50600.82, 'id': 1615219200, 'close': 53932.13, 'open': 51043.85}, {'amount': 19827903.05268399, 'vol': 363.5810368, 'high': 56417.86, 'low': 52500.0, 'id': 1615305600, 'close': 56316.89, 'open': 54136.23}, {'amount': 17712489.15241699, 'vol': 316.18844945, 'high': 57366.66, 'low': 54376.31, 'id': 1615392000, 'close': 56314.89, 'open': 56384.22}, {'amount': 14841092.038681, 'vol': 261.05357594, 'high': 58095.11, 'low': 55200.0, 'id': 1615478400, 'close': 56929.67, 'open': 56383.91}, {'amount': 14784195.028461, 'vol': 255.60144079, 'high': 60000.0, 'low': 56117.23, 'id': 1615564800, 'close': 59658.7, 'open': 57027.61}, {'amount': 80844948.29017998, 'vol': 1332.07403043, 'high': 61813.88, 'low': 59072.25, 'id': 1615651200, 'close': 59681.26, 'open': 59658.7}, {'amount': 205063509.176427, 'vol': 3556.03413821, 'high': 60702.1, 'low': 54704.52, 'id': 1615737600, 'close': 56233.82, 'open': 59709.37}, {'amount': 206866989.041811, 'vol': 3747.21705086, 'high': 56919.93, 'low': 53317.72, 'id': 1615824000, 'close': 55816.74, 'open': 56233.36}, {'amount': 97608757.082147, 'vol': 1756.34495485, 'high': 57139.92, 'low': 54302.3, 'id': 1615910400, 'close': 54942.36, 'open': 55863.4}, {'amount': 104265642.501531, 'vol': 1792.92604659, 'high': 59594.96, 'low': 54756.43, 'id': 1615996800, 'close': 59509.19, 'open': 54825.47}, {'amount': 124461243.004402, 'vol': 2140.81195655, 'high': 60076.79, 'low': 56317.93, 'id': 1616083200, 'close': 59043.39, 'open': 59514.79}, {'amount': 89710246.63177, 'vol': 1526.06234194, 'high': 59852.58, 'low': 57861.36, 'id': 1616169600, 'close': 59211.65, 'open': 58995.07}, {'amount': 107743717.64834, 'vol': 1875.1643, 'high': 59443.18, 'low': 55538.79, 'id': 1616256000, 'close': 57180.75, 'open': 59247.76}, {'amount': 80612082.874866, 'vol': 1406.91266052, 'high': 58386.99, 'low': 56325.05, 'id': 1616342400, 'close': 57082.87, 'open': 57151.95}, {'amount': 178298819.785085, 'vol': 3258.94847361, 'high': 57176.76, 'low': 53015.91, 'id': 1616428800, 'close': 55159.38, 'open': 57088.4}, {'amount': 119545237.17736799, 'vol': 2162.90997587, 'high': 57176.08, 'low': 53536.02, 'id': 1616515200, 'close': 56302.29, 'open': 55181.29}, {'amount': 238584882.445693, 'vol': 4538.06431876, 'high': 56400.78, 'low': 50473.31, 'id': 1616601600, 'close': 50940.36, 'open': 56300.89}, {'amount': 159906587.683254, 'vol': 3063.36785679, 'high': 53803.71, 'low': 50577.03, 'id': 1616688000, 'close': 53268.3, 'open': 50957.94}, {'amount': 91656693.23358999, 'vol': 1681.2160794, 'high': 55505.46, 'low': 52931.11, 'id': 1616774400, 'close': 54930.23, 'open': 53270.35}, {'amount': 75732857.95854199, 'vol': 1353.90943958, 'high': 56603.01, 'low': 54987.29, 'id': 1616860800, 'close': 56355.23, 'open': 54987.29}, {'amount': 93978191.31732899, 'vol': 1663.42586919, 'high': 58379.12, 'low': 54718.61, 'id': 1616947200, 'close': 57678.89, 'open': 56375.23}, {'amount': 91668267.23975, 'vol': 1580.09526937, 'high': 59331.06, 'low': 57090.36, 'id': 1617033600, 'close': 58539.89, 'open': 57723.04}, {'amount': 115553683.666343, 'vol': 1974.80181034, 'high': 59769.06, 'low': 56814.27, 'id': 1617120000, 'close': 59301.17, 'open': 58544.15}, {'amount': 97093422.519803, 'vol': 1648.20890851, 'high': 59625.57, 'low': 58151.14, 'id': 1617206400, 'close': 59022.94, 'open': 59293.43}, {'amount': 90843844.761572, 'vol': 1533.40729662, 'high': 60163.78, 'low': 57955.39, 'id': 1617292800, 'close': 59460.3, 'open': 59014.97}, {'amount': 43641928.23881799, 'vol': 738.37407381, 'high': 59773.77, 'low': 58496.62, 'id': 1617379200, 'close': 58850.57, 'open': 59535.36}, {'amount': 102250100.087108, 'vol': 1773.91721483, 'high': 59114.36, 'low': 56458.49, 'id': 1617465600, 'close': 57910.36, 'open': 58877.5}, {'amount': 53964534.621765, 'vol': 932.80963335, 'high': 59232.21, 'low': 56824.53, 'id': 1617552000, 'close': 58981.91, 'open': 57932.71}, {'amount': 76174526.410055, 'vol': 1299.1168925, 'high': 59466.61, 'low': 57440.95, 'id': 1617638400, 'close': 57832.29, 'open': 59043.7}, {'amount': 127934214.304791, 'vol': 2233.00844337, 'high': 58630.89, 'low': 55705.78, 'id': 1617724800, 'close': 56426.61, 'open': 57835.33}, {'amount': 94543574.283404, 'vol': 1670.96160995, 'high': 57890.88, 'low': 55494.62, 'id': 1617811200, 'close': 57760.88, 'open': 56426.61}, {'amount': 48507045.492986, 'vol': 834.63228103, 'high': 58868.88, 'low': 57476.85, 'id': 1617897600, 'close': 58217.52, 'open': 57772.69}, {'amount': 87395563.391595, 'vol': 1456.28554975, 'high': 61325.4, 'low': 57926.44, 'id': 1617984000, 'close': 60242.55, 'open': 58241.08}, {'amount': 89408768.929684, 'vol': 1497.1765454, 'high': 60605.86, 'low': 58407.51, 'id': 1618070400, 'close': 59661.57, 'open': 60269.69}, {'amount': 100395081.611961, 'vol': 1669.57226956, 'high': 61250.0, 'low': 59425.66, 'id': 1618156800, 'close': 60005.79, 'open': 59663.35}, {'amount': 108849773.918268, 'vol': 1765.18592506, 'high': 63627.23, 'low': 59722.19, 'id': 1618243200, 'close': 63334.17, 'open': 59986.83}, {'amount': 132669199.387004, 'vol': 2083.84049863, 'high': 64816.43, 'low': 62442.48, 'id': 1618329600, 'close': 63048.86, 'open': 63366.42}, {'amount': 102379338.44118299, 'vol': 1634.80072547, 'high': 63734.05, 'low': 61344.8, 'id': 1618416000, 'close': 62750.77, 'open': 63055.19}, {'amount': 124496816.29539499, 'vol': 2021.47815294, 'high': 63749.84, 'low': 60128.03, 'id': 1618502400, 'close': 61577.53, 'open': 62718.42}, {'amount': 70374322.42502499, 'vol': 1143.52479955, 'high': 62493.47, 'low': 60118.04, 'id': 1618588800, 'close': 60295.68, 'open': 61583.15}, {'amount': 220507509.7622058, 'vol': 3938.84947277, 'high': 60870.54, 'low': 51553.71, 'id': 1618675200, 'close': 55465.46, 'open': 60216.86}, {'amount': 146632879.598943, 'vol': 2606.98264399, 'high': 57491.51, 'low': 54291.64, 'id': 1618761600, 'close': 54596.37, 'open': 55470.34}, {'amount': 157120605.485988, 'vol': 2851.58529387, 'high': 56583.01, 'low': 53372.4, 'id': 1618848000, 'close': 55337.03, 'open': 54549.23}, {'amount': 91420679.33259611, 'vol': 1643.69036967, 'high': 57036.21, 'low': 54318.71, 'id': 1618934400, 'close': 56128.37, 'open': 55345.71}, {'amount': 112014153.3375608, 'vol': 2068.517683, 'high': 56285.51, 'low': 52596.97, 'id': 1619020800, 'close': 54633.36, 'open': 56160.08}, {'amount': 328452790.175815, 'vol': 6556.50166802, 'high': 55106.26, 'low': 47579.51, 'id': 1619107200, 'close': 49834.01, 'open': 54674.48}, {'amount': 135897217.837118, 'vol': 2724.30141412, 'high': 51236.3, 'low': 48706.46, 'id': 1619193600, 'close': 50225.81, 'open': 49812.75}, {'amount': 86225582.40173198, 'vol': 1725.78739786, 'high': 50977.16, 'low': 49119.83, 'id': 1619280000, 'close': 50237.99, 'open': 50240.83}, {'amount': 162008223.315922, 'vol': 3166.71788761, 'high': 53879.1, 'low': 47014.11, 'id': 1619366400, 'close': 53537.58, 'open': 50285.71}, {'amount': 153442382.617714, 'vol': 2840.1670967, 'high': 55268.88, 'low': 52627.76, 'id': 1619452800, 'close': 55015.88, 'open': 53592.2}, {'amount': 102589090.874518, 'vol': 1871.27129897, 'high': 55696.53, 'low': 53830.92, 'id': 1619539200, 'close': 54330.49, 'open': 55009.61}, {'amount': 78447359.97928, 'vol': 1442.07050322, 'high': 56396.87, 'low': 53328.78, 'id': 1619625600, 'close': 53718.83, 'open': 54310.34}, {'amount': 116793674.119134, 'vol': 2154.73691295, 'high': 57217.16, 'low': 52368.64, 'id': 1619712000, 'close': 57169.6, 'open': 53722.09}, {'amount': 96570142.35388927, 'vol': 1679.28326092, 'high': 58439.28, 'low': 56309.1, 'id': 1619798400, 'close': 57323.54, 'open': 57207.57}, {'amount': 82501050.655198, 'vol': 1449.50552847, 'high': 57957.46, 'low': 56081.45, 'id': 1619884800, 'close': 56582.46, 'open': 57365.31}, {'amount': 84990164.87461, 'vol': 1472.01083694, 'high': 58955.31, 'low': 56229.87, 'id': 1619971200, 'close': 57590.88, 'open': 56600.85}, {'amount': 170747147.11335, 'vol': 3054.1306154, 'high': 58143.36, 'low': 53592.97, 'id': 1620057600, 'close': 53812.54, 'open': 57622.64}, {'amount': 174079533.39853132, 'vol': 3173.15941312, 'high': 57681.57, 'low': 52956.14, 'id': 1620144000, 'close': 57607.72, 'open': 53790.56}, {'amount': 143883015.870157, 'vol': 2515.10330672, 'high': 58340.37, 'low': 56382.54, 'id': 1620230400, 'close': 57088.11, 'open': 57656.74}, {'amount': 139790325.476696, 'vol': 2482.37048956, 'high': 57642.64, 'low': 55266.56, 'id': 1620316800, 'close': 57418.16, 'open': 57120.76}, {'amount': 122105838.228945, 'vol': 2100.67576497, 'high': 59395.15, 'low': 56790.38, 'id': 1620403200, 'close': 57577.26, 'open': 57418.16}, {'amount': 115045410.693198, 'vol': 1977.61373943, 'high': 59474.65, 'low': 56322.43, 'id': 1620489600, 'close': 57389.13, 'open': 57630.36}, {'amount': 114991563.064466, 'vol': 1982.03106642, 'high': 59482.14, 'low': 56728.69, 'id': 1620576000, 'close': 58299.0, 'open': 57389.13}, {'amount': 186919686.52095872, 'vol': 3356.79334638, 'high': 58533.79, 'low': 53582.33, 'id': 1620662400, 'close': 56017.06, 'open': 58288.41}, {'amount': 103513288.61693467, 'vol': 1831.39944841, 'high': 57966.42, 'low': 55291.95, 'id': 1620748800, 'close': 55483.35, 'open': 56026.65}, {'amount': 288801818.24797094, 'vol': 5660.12359346, 'high': 55608.89, 'low': 46140.79, 'id': 1620835200, 'close': 49643.71, 'open': 55458.73}, {'amount': 253658267.75285453, 'vol': 5141.53277422, 'high': 51445.65, 'low': 47020.57, 'id': 1620921600, 'close': 51221.63, 'open': 49651.48}, {'amount': 203234524.036813, 'vol': 4121.44511409, 'high': 51304.09, 'low': 47795.57, 'id': 1621008000, 'close': 48968.64, 'open': 51247.35}, {'amount': 218899439.62403107, 'vol': 4553.68292732, 'high': 49772.2, 'low': 46504.03, 'id': 1621094400, 'close': 47742.56, 'open': 48949.8}, {'amount': 393753122.476445, 'vol': 8754.01261541, 'high': 48072.39, 'low': 42212.67, 'id': 1621180800, 'close': 43373.31, 'open': 47716.16}, {'amount': 274234585.06329924, 'vol': 6217.50603307, 'high': 45782.3, 'low': 42174.06, 'id': 1621267200, 'close': 42995.93, 'open': 43325.75}, {'amount': 421715102.819913, 'vol': 10564.41383044, 'high': 43796.58, 'low': 30019.0, 'id': 1621353600, 'close': 37278.21, 'open': 42946.74}, {'amount': 514868986.042775, 'vol': 13243.72393704, 'high': 42385.5, 'low': 34932.54, 'id': 1621440000, 'close': 41396.59, 'open': 37274.92}, {'amount': 333805362.3166438, 'vol': 8340.53136852, 'high': 42184.47, 'low': 36522.08, 'id': 1621526400, 'close': 36722.17, 'open': 41415.92}, {'amount': 378307991.23155874, 'vol': 10260.01073065, 'high': 38799.32, 'low': 33522.99, 'id': 1621612800, 'close': 38184.83, 'open': 36788.96}, {'amount': 340447014.8667959, 'vol': 9547.37395748, 'high': 38526.89, 'low': 32689.36, 'id': 1621699200, 'close': 33320.96, 'open': 38170.56}, {'amount': 307805348.883181, 'vol': 8698.04326565, 'high': 38606.99, 'low': 31155.22, 'id': 1621785600, 'close': 37553.73, 'open': 33303.95}, {'amount': 290220569.63238615, 'vol': 7620.08486737, 'high': 39846.3, 'low': 36474.39, 'id': 1621872000, 'close': 38298.65, 'open': 37550.66}, {'amount': 152972365.570099, 'vol': 3922.35179881, 'high': 40787.75, 'low': 37158.7, 'id': 1621958400, 'close': 38731.58, 'open': 38280.39}, {'amount': 165382979.803872, 'vol': 4275.48800241, 'high': 40342.89, 'low': 37157.41, 'id': 1622044800, 'close': 39679.56, 'open': 38741.72}, {'amount': 198430485.9960131, 'vol': 5325.62871165, 'high': 39699.39, 'low': 35122.52, 'id': 1622131200, 'close': 36727.01, 'open': 39699.39}, {'amount': 224682255.143132, 'vol': 6330.86171401, 'high': 37288.8, 'low': 33863.46, 'id': 1622217600, 'close': 34405.12, 'open': 36737.12}, {'amount': 173097338.191752, 'vol': 4978.57968063, 'high': 36467.55, 'low': 33420.06, 'id': 1622304000, 'close': 35495.68, 'open': 34380.84}]}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code.

Comment: `if('high'):` is pointless - a non-empty string is always truthy. Access the list by key from the dictionary, slice the last five items.

Comment: `if('high')` doesn't do anything (it's the same as if you did `if True`).  Do you want the 5 highest `'high'` values from the `kline_data` list, or the last ones in the order given?

Comment: There are 25 'high' values ​​in these results. I need the last 5 'high' values. So 'high' = 21,22,23,24,25th values

Comment: I am somewhat new to python programming. How can I reach the last 5 'high' values ​​that I said exactly? How should I add something to my code?

Comment: Any basic tutorial like https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html covers how to interact with lists and dictionaries, I'd suggest doing some structured learning.

Comment: Need the last 5 'high' values ​​in the given order?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the last five values like this using list sclicing and negative indexing.

```
for data in klines['kline_data'][-5:]:
    print(data['high'])
```